# Perl Simple Regexp

Tags: regex, perl

I have a valid string, `somestr xyztip`, where `xyz` is optional. But if `xyz` does exist, it needs to be next to `tip` (no whitespace).
So valid strings are: `somestr tip` or `somestr xyztip`.

An invalid string would be: `somestr xyz tip`  (space between `xyz` and `tip`)

I've tried many combinations, but I can't get the regexp to balk at a space between 'xyz' & 'tip'.  The one below is what I would think should work:

```
/^.+?\s(xyz)?tip$/
```

The problem is the syntax before the '(xyz)?' - that is the '.+?\s' .  This is saying any char 1 or more times, not greedy followed by a single whitespace.

what am I missing here?

Comment: what are you trying to capture?

Comment: So `xyz` cannot be anywhere in the string unless it comes directly before `tip`?  So would the strings `'tuvwxyz tip'` and `'tuvwxyz xyztip'` be invalid?

Comment: Is `somestr` irrelevant? I.e. you are looking for the string `xyztip`, but not `xyz tip`?

Comment: Correct, somestr is irrelevant in much as there is content before the optional 'xyz'.

Comment: So, @CraigP... that means "somexyzstr tip" and "somexyzstr xyztip" are valid, but "somexyzstr xyz tip" is not... right?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `xyz` cannot be anywhere in the string except for immediately before `tip`, the following should work:

```
/^((?!xyz).)+\s(xyz)?tip$/
```

This changes the `.+?` to `((?!xyz).)+`.  By putting the negative lookahead within the repeating group we can match any number of characters but stop if we encounter `xyz`, so `((?!xyz).)+` would match "foo" from "fooxyz".  This allows us to make sure that `xyz` is never matched by the first part of the regex, so that if it exists it has to be in the `(xyz)?tip` portion of the regex.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a "zero width positive look-ahead assertion"... so, your regex would look something like:

```
\S+\s(?:xyz)?(?=tip)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

From `perldoc perlre`:

```
"(?=pattern)"
    A zero-width positive look-ahead assertion.  For example, "/\w+(?=\t)/"
    matches a word followed by a tab, without including the tab in $&.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
^(?>[^ ]++| (?!xyz))+ (?:xyz)?tip$
```

Comment: Thanks for all your responses ... with look-ahead assertion, it doesn't appear to recognize whitespace-type code (i.e. - \s).

Comment: Sorry, this is better: ^\S+ (?:xyz)?tip$

Comment: @CraigP: Sure, but with this pattern, `somestr` can not contain spaces.

Comment: @CraigP: the pattern `^.+?\S (?:xyz)?tip$` will work too but will be slower.